# Progress Text for Features Wix

Tags: wix

Can anyone recommend a way of doing this:

I have my main application and depending on a few conditions the customer has the option install the files for 7 drivers relating to the main application. The problem is they would like for the progress text to be updated something like:

If feature 1 is selected then add text "Installing Feature 1"

Any ideas how I would achieve this as as far as I am aware we can only set progress text for custom action..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I set the `ADDLOCAL` property to `CustomActionData`:

```
 <CustomAction Id="SetAddLocalProperty" Return="check" Property="InstallDrivers" Value="[ADDLOCAL]"></CustomAction>
```

Then, I scheduled this custom action to run before calling the `InstallDriver` custom action:

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall InstallDrivers(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    LPWSTR szValueBuf = NULL;
    char CustomActionData[MAX_PATH];
    const UINT iTickIncrement = 1000;
    const UINT iNumberItems = 3;
    const UINT iTotalTicks = iTickIncrement * iNumberItems;
    PMSIHANDLE hActionRec = MsiCreateRecord(10);
    PMSIHANDLE hProgressRec = MsiCreateRecord(3);

    hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "InstallDrivers");
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

    hr = WcaGetProperty(L"CustomActionData",&szValueBuf);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get CustomActionData");

    wcstombs(CustomActionData, szValueBuf, 260);

    char *token = strtok(CustomActionData, ",");

    while (token != NULL) 
    {
        MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 1, TEXT("MyCustomAction"));

        if (strcmp(token, "Driver1") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver1"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "Driver2") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver2"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "Driver3") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver3"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "Driver4") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver4"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "Driver5") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver5"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "Driver6") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver6"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "Driver7") ==0)
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT("Installing Driver7"));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }   
        else
        {
            MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 2, TEXT(""));
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
        }

        MsiRecordSetString(hActionRec, 3, TEXT("Incrementing tick [1] of [2]"));

        UINT iResult = MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONSTART, hActionRec);
        if ((iResult == IDCANCEL))
            return ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT;


        MsiRecordSetInteger(hProgressRec, 1, 1);
        MsiRecordSetInteger(hProgressRec, 2, 1);
        MsiRecordSetInteger(hProgressRec, 3, 0);
        iResult = MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS, hProgressRec);
        if ((iResult == IDCANCEL))
            return ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT;

        MsiRecordSetInteger(hProgressRec, 1, 2);
        MsiRecordSetInteger(hProgressRec, 2, iTickIncrement);
        MsiRecordSetInteger(hProgressRec, 3, 0);

        MsiRecordSetInteger(hActionRec, 2, iTotalTicks);

        for( int i = 0; i < iTotalTicks; i+=iTickIncrement)
        {
            MsiRecordSetInteger(hActionRec, 1, i);

            iResult = MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA, hActionRec);
            if ((iResult == IDCANCEL))
                return ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT;

            iResult = MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_PROGRESS, hProgressRec);
            if ((iResult == IDCANCEL))
                return ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT;

            Sleep(1000);            
        }
    }

    LExit:
    er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```